# how to write lwuit radio button code

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, state-machine

I have my form Welcome on this form i have two radio buttons-Verification and enrollment and a OK button .when user select one of radio buttons and press OK then a form will show but i am not able to do that. Please help.

this is my Statemachine class code:

```
package userclasses;

import generated.StateMachineBase;
import com.sun.lwuit.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.events.*;
import com.sun.lwuit.RadioButton;
import com.sun.lwuit.Form;
import com.sun.lwuit.util.Resources;

public class StateMachine extends StateMachineBase implements ActionListener {

    Resources resources;
    RadioButton Verification = new RadioButton("Verification");
    RadioButton Enrollment = new RadioButton("Enrollment");
    StateMachineBase cl = new StateMachineBase() { };

    com.sun.lwuit.ButtonGroup bg=new ButtonGroup();

    Form fo, f;

    public StateMachine(String resFile) {
        super(resFile);
        // do not modify, write code in initVars and initialize class members there,
        // the constructor might be invoked too late due to race conditions that might occur
    }

    /**
     * this method should be used to initialize variables instead of
     * the constructor/class scope to avoid race conditions
     */
    StateMachine()
    {
        try {
            resources = Resources.open("/NEW AADHAR.res");
        }
        catch(java.io.IOException err) {
            err.printStackTrace();
        }
        cl.setHomeForm("Welcome");
        fo = (Form)cl.startApp(resources,null,true);
        f = cl.findWelcome(fo);
        //fo.addCommandListener(this);

        Verification = cl.findRadioButton1(f);
        Enrollment = cl.findRadioButton(f);
        f.addComponent(Verification);
        f.addComponent(Enrollment);
        //fo.addComponent(bg,null);
        bg.add(Enrollment);
        bg.add(Verification);
        Verification.addActionListener(this);
        Enrollment.addActionListener(this);
    }

    protected  void initVars() { }

    protected void onWelcome_OKAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) { }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

    protected boolean onWelcomeEXIT() {
        // If the resource file changes the names of components this call will break   notifying you that you should fix the code
        boolean val = super.onWelcomeEXIT();
        return val;
    }

    protected void onWelcome_ButtonAction(Component c, ActionEvent event) {
        // If the resource file changes the names of components this call will break notifying you that you should fix the code  

        super.onWelcome_RadioButton1Action(c, event);
        super.onWelcome_RadioButtonAction(c, event);

        if(Verification.hasFocus()) {   
            showForm("Login",null);
        }
        else if(Enrollment.hasFocus()) {
            showForm("Authentication",null);
        }
        else {
            Dialog.show("INFORMATION","Please select option","OK","CANCEL");
        }
    }
|
```

Answer (score 3):

When you generate a netbeans project from the GUI builder the src folder will now contain the res file you need to work with. Whenever you modify the GUI code that StateMachineBase will be regenerated so you can just rename the components in the GUI builder (you can do this by clicking on the tree node and pressing F2 or by selecting the name attribute in the properties table).
The properties table allows you to assign an event for every component that supports it (e.g. radio button action events) which will generate the appropriate callback method in the StateMachine class (write your code only in the StateMachine class).

Radio buttons can be associated with one group by giving them the same group name.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to use Resource Editor. Simply run it from LWUIT/util directory.

To create project using this tool follow each step from this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HOfb8qiySd8. Be sure to watch it to the end.

It will create 4 Netbeans projects (ProjectName, ProjectName_Desktop, ProjectName_MIDP, ProjectName_RIM). Fix depedencies (most important for ProjectName and _MIDP one) and you can start coding.

File StateMachineBase.java will be located in 'generated' package, which means that it will be regenerated every time you change something in Resource Editor.

Implement everything in StateMachine class ('userclasses' package), but don't create new methods there, use Resource Editor to create them for you: Resource Editor -> GUI Builder (tab on left side) -> Select component -> Events (tab on the right).

Now, if you want to do something for example, you want to change TextField value, you will write something like this:

```
protected boolean onUstawieniaKontoZapisz() {
// If the resource file changes the names of components this call will break notifying you that you should fix the code //this comment was generated
boolean val = super.onUstawieniaKontoZapisz(); //generated

Form current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();

TextField login = findUstawieniaKontoLoginTextField(current); //TextField name in Editor is: 'UstawieniaKontoLoginTextField' - a bit long I know, but it's unique
TextField password = findUstawieniaKontoHasloTextField(current); //same here, 'UstawieniaKontoHasloTextField' is second's TextField name

Configuration.setEmail(login.getText()); //Configuration class is used to store preferences
Configuration.setPassword(password.getText());

return val; //generated
}
```

You can find all 'find*' methods inside StateMachineBase class. There is one for each Component you have added using Resource Editor (GUI Builder tab).

For grouping radio buttons into groups use Resource Editor too, select each radio button and on Properties tab find 'Group' property. Set it to the same word on every radio button you want to have in the same group.